# Custom Commands on Terminal with pipe character

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe

I need to make some custom commands on Ubuntu, everything is working fine until I found that my new custom command requires to have | as a input parameter.
So, when I created my function it is not recognizing the part after pipe as a command and throwing command not found error.
i.e.

```
function listhorizontal(){
echo "1st line"
echo "hello $1"
echo "3rd line"
}

#output
ubuntu:~$ listhorizontal JohnDoe
1st line
hello JohnDoe
3rd line
```

it's working, but when I try for a command that has | like:

```
function getwithpipe(){
if [[ $1 =~ "|" ]]
then
   echo "It's there!"
fi

}
#output
ubuntu:~$ getwithpipe stringcontains|fortest
fortest: command not found
```

then it won't work.

Is there a possibility to change the mapping for pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape or quote any shell-special characters ex.

```
$ getwithpipe stringcontains\|fortest
It's there!
```

or

```
$ getwithpipe "stringcontains|fortest"
It's there!
```

Comment: so there is no way of changing the default pipe command to a different character? only modifying my custom command!

Comment: @virusivv I never like to say "no way" - for example, you could write your own shell in which `|` is an ordinary character

Comment: well that's a way to go, but I don't have that much time, anyway thanks :)